# Extract some atribute values with regex wether other atributes are present or not

Tags: c#, regex

I'am having hard times trying to get my values with regex in an XML like line

```
<themes:MetaGrid x:Key="external_liquid_waste" x:Shared="False" Categories="LiquidsAndWastes,Others" Group="XD">
```

I'm trying to retreive only the values of `key` and `categories` attributes wether the `Group` or the `x:Shared` attributes are present or not.

The separators in the category attribute can be either a coma, a semicolon or a whitespace.

So far (before adding the Group attribute) I was using this expression :

```
<.+MetaGrid.+x:Key="(?<reskey>[\w]+)".+Categories="(?<resca>.+)".+>
```

But with the group attriute, the second capture returns `LiquidsAndWastes" Group=` which is not good.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks !!

Comment: Make yourself a favor and just use an XML parser, like `XDocument.Load`.

Comment: Yep, this is easier indeed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML parser would be the way to go here. But, if you really want to use a regex, see below.

```
<.+MetaGrid.+x:Key="(?<reskey>[\w]+)".+Categories="(?<resca>.+?)".+>
```

Notice the `?` in the second capture group, so the group is matched in a non-greedy fashion.

Comment: It Worked perfectly. Thanks !